# Pandas sum in time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data looks like:

```
ID  A   Date        B
1   5   2019-01-01  4
1   5   2019-01-03  6
1   5   2019-01-15  8
2   9   2019-01-02  2
2   9   2019-01-18  3
```

And i wont to be:

[Result column C]

```
ID  A   Date        B   **C**
1   5   2019-01-01  4   **9**
1   5   2019-01-03  6   **15**
1   5   2019-01-15  8   **23**
2   9   2019-01-02  2   **11**
2   9   2019-01-18  3   **14**
```

```
C[0] = A[0] + B[0] (9)

C[1] = A[1] + B[0] + B[1] (where B[0] + B[1] is C[1]=15)

C[0] = A[2] + B[0] + B[1] + B[2] (where B[0] + B[1] + B[2] is C[2]=23)

C[0] = A[3] + B[3] 

C[0] = A[4] + B[3] + B[4]
```

I solved by for loop, but on 2M row is unacceptable by time execution.

Does anyone have a better approach? Thanks to everyone who wants to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`df.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
In [544]: df['C'] = df.groupby('ID').B.cumsum() + df.A

In [545]: df
Out[545]: 
   ID  A        Date  B   C
0   1  5  2019-01-01  4   9
1   1  5  2019-01-03  6  15
2   1  5  2019-01-15  8  23
3   2  9  2019-01-02  2  11
4   2  9  2019-01-18  3  14
```

Comment: This is a great! Thanks a lot!